# FileManager For TinyMCE not getting variable

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG editor.
It is working perfectly, except for the image upload directory. I want each user to have their own directory in the images directory, but I cannot get it to work.

I am passing the user id in the URL and have tried adding the code to get it from the URL in the config.php file where the directories are defined, but the `$user_id` value remains empty.

Any assistance would be great.

The URL:

```
http://mydomain.co.za/index.php?user_id=1
```

The Code:

```
<?php
$user_id= htmlspecialchars($_GET["user_id"]);

// The URL that points to the upload folder on your site. 
// Can be a relative or full URL (include the protocol and domain)
$imageURL = 'http://mydomain.co.za/images/'.$user_id;
// Full upload system path. Make sure you have write permissions to this folder
$uploadPath = '/home/username/public_html/editor/images/'.$user_id;
//We create the directory if it does not exist - you can remove this if you consider it a security risk
if(!is_dir($uploadPath)) {
    mkdir($uploadPath,0755,true);
}

//Create thumb directory if doesn't exist
if(!is_dir($uploadPath . 'thumbnail')) {
    mkdir($uploadPath . 'thumbnail',0755,true);
}

//Allowed extenstions
$allowedExtensions = array('jpg','gif','jpeg','bmp','tif','png'); 
//Maximum upload limit
$sizeLimit = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

function isAuth() {
    //Perform your own authorization to make sure user is allowed to upload
    return true;
}
```

Is it possible the reason is because it is not in the main php file?
Or Can I get the variable from the URL?

They suggested on their [Instructions](http://www.binpress.com/app/tinymce-image-uploader-manager/23) that I add `$userId = Auth::getId();` but id returns an empty value. Plus I have no idea what that command is executing.

**PLEASE NOTE:**
the file management is being done by [TinyMCE Image Uploader & Manager](http://www.binpress.com/app/tinymce-image-uploader-manager/23)

**UPDATE:**

By adding the `$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; echo $actual_link;` I noticed by the time the $_GET command is rung the URL has changed to http://mydomain.co.za/tinymce/plugins/lioniteimages/connector/php/gallery.php, but in the browser URL bar, the URL is still the same with the variable.

Is there anyway to access that URL instead of the one i am getting?

Comment: This description seems very disjointed. Can't make sense of your examples. How is the image uploaded, via `POST`? How does the page get from your expected URL to the one you're having problems with?

Comment: @Twisty I am sorry, i could not make sense of what was going on myself. The more I looked into it, the more I got confused... But I found the solution. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Simple enough, just created a session and the problem was solved.

I was able to get the variable from the session.